# delete blurred part of online website to be visible, without paying

Tags: html, css

Recently I am visiting a website,

 but that website makes not visible a section by blurring it (and wants me to pay to see what there is)

I want that I can read through the blurred part of that website.

I read on the internet that there is some code that can solve this. (maybe with javascript or css)

> if someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> like he said @Dai, is better to pay if you really want that content. 
> this is my suggestion, but I will help you the same

---

**one line answer**

just add a `*` selector with this css code `filter: blur(0) !important;`

so it  will become like this:

```css
* {
  filter: blur(0) !important;
}
```

---

**why does it work?**

> most of the websites for adding the blurring effect, 
>  they use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) CSS property

---

if the code I show to you before,

 don't work, then try using also [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) CSS property.

the logic is the same: `backdrop-filter: blur(0) !important;`

```css
* {
  filter: blur(0) !important;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0) !important;
}
```

> thank @Dai for the suggestion here!

---

**how to use this code?**

1. open devtools on the page.

    <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. click "+" icon

    [image]
3. change the selector to `*`

    [image]
4. add the line of code of before.

    [image]

---

**how it works?**

so we basically reset that blur 
to all HTML elements using `*` selector.

so we don't worry about where there is the
element blurred. 
by this, I mean that there are websites that make it difficult to find the element blurred: 
 *(for example "news websites", etc...)*

- by adding multiple filters
- or nesting the blurred element
- or adding the `blur` effect inline so normal CSS can't override it.
  etc...

> use also [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) that make the resetting of the filter also in inline [`style=""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

---

**it can't do results all the time**

> **remember:** there are also some websites that blur the content, but there isn't any real valuable content behind it (for example "LinkedIn" they do that, etc...)

[image]

in this example, you can see there is the same component with the same text, and there isn't any valuable content for you (try maybe in that website it will work)

[image]